# impossible gpg signature verification

Tags: gnupg

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/cryptsetup/v1.7/cryptsetup-1.7.3.tar.xz
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/cryptsetup/v1.7/cryptsetup-1.7.3.tar.sign
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/cryptsetup/v1.7/sha256sums.asc
```

shasum verified: ok

```
gpg --verify cryptsetup-1.7.3.tar.sign cryptsetup-1.7.3.tar.xz
```

the output is bad :

```
gpg: Signature made Sun 30 Oct 2016 01:56:01 PM UTC using RSA key ID D93E98FC
gpg: BAD signature from "Milan Broz <gmazyland@gmail.com>"
```

then

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/cryptsetup/v1.7/v1.7.3-ReleaseNotes
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/cryptsetup/v1.7/v1.7.3-ReleaseNotes.sign

gpg --verify v1.7.3-ReleaseNotes.sign v1.7.3-ReleaseNotes
```

this is good (although the warning):

```
gpg: Signature made Sun 30 Oct 2016 01:56:09 PM UTC using RSA key ID D93E98FC
gpg: Good signature from "Milan Broz <gmazyland@gmail.com>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 2A29 1824 3FDE 4664 8D06  86F9 D9B0 577B D93E 98FC
```

I make another test on another website:

```
wget https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/gnupg/gnupg-2.0.30.tar.bz2
wget https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/gnupg/gnupg-2.0.30.tar.bz2.sig
```

and everything is good as well.

Then I go to the author's blog (Milan Broz's blog), but the download link leads to the same website.

I tried some previous packages and had the same issue:

cryptsetup-1.7.1.tar.sign with cryptsetup-1.7.1.tar.gz & cryptsetup-1.7.1.tar.xz

cryptsetup-1.7.2.tar.sign with cryptsetup-1.7.2.tar.gz & cryptsetup-1.7.2.tar.xz

If I miss something here, plz tell me what.
otherwise, is there a place where I can have a correctly signed version of this software?

thanx folks.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a place where I can have a correctly signed version of this software?

Try from the official website: https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup (now -- Nov. 2017, 9 months later, in 1.7.5 or 2.0-rc1)

> this is good (although the warning):

The warning is expected. See "[Check PGP Signature and Install Veracrypt 1.17](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=221631)":

> The "`WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature! There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.`" means that the Veracrypt public key is not signed by you or by anybody whose key you have signed, so there is no direct line of trust between you and the Veracrypt developers.
>   **This is as expected**.